# Add a constraint with condition using the current time

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, constraints, unique-constraint

How can I make a constraint that is checking a condition that compares one of the column values with the current time?
I have Patient, Doctor, and Appointments models, each Patient can not schedule more than one Appointment for the future for the same doctor, I want to make a constraint enforcing that.

```
Patient table has the columns below:
 - Id (unique)
 - Name

Doctor table:
 - Id (unique)
 - Name

Appointment table:
 - FK to Patient table
 - FK to Doctor table
 - scheduled_to (timestamp) when the appointment will occur/occurred
```

The idea is that any patient won't have more than one appointment scheduled for the future.
For clarification, I want that the DB won't allow me to create two appointments for the same (Patient, Doctor) with a future scheduled_to, but any number of appointments from the past are not a problem to have.

How can I enforce that on the DB side?

Comment: Your appointment should have a start and end, rather than just a start. If you do that, you can use an [exclusion constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) to prevent overlapping appointments

Comment: It do work, but a patient will be able to create 2 future appointments (just no overlapping times).

Comment: Research INSERT triggers. See the first NOTE at the end of the CHECK CONSTRAINT section of the documentation.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS